# Stripe: OAuth Flow Automation? Webhook Timeliness?

Tags: rest, oauth, stripe-payments, webhooks

Having waited a week for an answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40426194/1337498) -- and being generally fed up with the poor quality of *Brand X*'s documentation and support -- I'm re-casting that question here in terms of [Stripe](https://stripe.com/).

---

**The use case:**

There's a web service **S** that takes a bunch of user input via a REST API, and uses that input to generate, for a fee, some answer that it returns via the API. As a concrete but fictional example, you could think of the input as being the user's natal information, and the output being a horoscope for the user.

**S** is just a computation engine with an API; it doesn't offer a user interface. The presentation interfaces for human users are provided by channel-partner websites **P<sub>i</sub>**, each with its own look and feel, and its own financial arrangements with its customers. A **P<sub>i</sub>** may charge its customers a monthly membership fee, or it may pass charges for third party services like **S** through to users, but **S** neither knows nor care about the details of those arrangements.

Each **P<sub>i</sub>** pays, on behalf one of its customers **C**, the fee for the service that **S** provides to **C** when **C** requests the service. For its part, **S** will not return an answer for a particular instance of use until the fee for that instance has verifiably been paid by the **P<sub>i</sub>**.

---

**The questions:**

In several respects, there seems to be a fairly direct analogy between this use case and a case in which a driver (the service provider **S**) works for two or more ride-sharing companies (the channel partners **P<sub>i</sub>**). Each partner platform presents a unique look and feel to its customers, but offers the same underlying service, and pays its service provider(s) after taking its cut for each instance of use of the service.

However, there are a couple of notable differences, each of which leads to a separate sub-question.

First, Stripe's [OAuth Flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#oauth-flow) for connecting to a service provider's standalone account assumes that there is a human user in the loop who will interact with web *pages* to authorize the connection.

**Q1.** *Does Stripe offer a well-defined, stable REST API that allows a chunk of code on **S** to reliably act in the role of the presumed human user to authorize the account connection?*

Second, the web service **S** requires proof-of-payment from the channel partner site before returning its answer to the end customer -- or, in terms of the analogy, before letting the passenger out of the car! :-). I understand that **S** can set up a [webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to notify it of events that occur in/on its Stripe account (including, explicitly, "a charge being captured"), but:

**Q2.** *How much time lag (if any) might I expect between deposit of the payment into **S**'s Stripe account and delivery of the webhook?*

**S** can tolerate a small amount of delay in the delivery of the webhook, but obviously, the less the better. If the webhook is delivered synchronously as part of the deposit flow, that would be ideal -- for me, anyway :-) -- but if it goes into a queue to be delivered later, delays of more than a few minutes could be problematic.

---

Hope y'all Stripe users can do better by me than *Brand X*'s "[community](https://developer.paypal.com/support/)" did...

Comment: Could you perhaps be looking for [managed accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts), as opposed to standalone accounts that use an OAuth flow?

Comment: @korben -- Definitely not looking for managed accounts. The owners of **S** want complete visibility and access to the account into which charges are created and deposits are made.

Comment: Also, if the account was a managed account, and thus essentially "hidden" from **S**, how could **S** set up a webhook to report events occurring on it?

Comment: That actually sounds like *exactly* what you want then.  If *S* is a Platform Account and *Pi* represent your Connected (Managed) Accounts; *S* would be given the power to create/destroy the accounts, their payment methods, etc.  They have *full* control over the Connected Account as if it was their own, even though it represents another user.  Think of Uber/Lyft/etc. as *S*; and *Pi* as drivers-- the drivers don't have to make a connected accounts, but they can still be paid out.  Uber/Lyft/etc. take care of that FOR the driver and do the work.

Comment: But the problem statement is the other way around. S is the service provider (the "driver" in the analogy), and the channel partners Pi (the Lyfts/Ubers in the analogy) resell S's service to their customers, and remit, after taking their cuts, to S's account. So really the Pi are the platforms.

Comment: Gotcha.  Sorry for my misunderstanding.  Standalone accounts do sound like what you're looking for then.  If you kept a record of all of the client id's for each Platform and put a common site domain inside of the redirect URIs, you could have multiple connections on a single page, but you still wouldn't be able to automatically perform the action of connecting the two accounts, because you need the user to authorize their account (by logging in, logging out and then logging in, or fully creating a new one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1** - Perhaps I've misunderstood this question?

But-- if you're wondering if you can execute the OAuth flow on behalf of the user and authorize them without them having to do something; then "no".  That would somewhat defeat the purpose of the whole flow.

**Q2** - There is no guaranteed delivery timeframe for webhooks.  They're processed by a number of workers and their output is dependent on the volume of events they're processing at any given time.  Stripe tries to ensure they're out in under a minute or two, but that isn't something Stripe promises will always happen.

Comment: In this scenario, **S** _**is**_ the user -- i.e., the service provider who wants to authorize a channel partner to create charges and deposit payments into **S**''s _own_ Stripe account. This is something that **S** only ever does once per channel partner that resells its service, so it seems silly to make each channel partner implement full-on HTML pages that will only ever be used once, and equally silly to require a human employee of **S** to navigate those pages manually, rather than just issuing a command from **S**'s backend admin interface that runs the OAuth flow in an automated way.

Comment: Also, a minute or two of lag time for webhook delivery is fine, and if some small percentage of transactions take longer, that's probably fine too.

Comment: Out-of-band, it was pointed out to me that since there's a requirement for *S* to _log in_ to its Stripe account as part of the OAuth flow. If 2-factor authentication is enabled on **S**'s account (as it should be), this makes a human in the loop pretty much essential.